# Brightness below system minimun

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

Is there tool or application that can set the brightness of the screen below the system minimum?

Comment: Use screen filler pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favorite for this task is [ScreenFilter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor), which is completely free (no ads, even) and has [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) integration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are a dozen of them, go to the below link and download the app.

Vote up and choose answer if I helped :D

[NightMode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.bbarao.nightmode)